# Dynamic fields end up with wrong field name indexed into solr

Tags: json, solrj

I'm using solr 6.6 with solrJ 6.6. I have some code that is reading in json objects using Gson, and I have annotations for SolrJ so I can index objects. I'm doing something wrong with the combination of Gson and SolrJ, but I'm not sure what exactly.

My issue is that one of the fields is a dynamic field and it ends up being indexed with part of the regex value that SolrJ creates for dynamic fields.

What I would like/expect is to have the following json indexed into solr with the fields "id" and "spell_text_en-us".

```
{"id":"abc123", "spell_text_en-us":"abc123"}
```

Instead, solr ends up with the fields "id" and "spell_text_.*".

Here is a schema snippet:

```
<dynamicField name="spell_text_*" type="spell" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Here is an example of the solr document as returned by a solr query:

```
{
  "id": "70427-7534088-de",
  "spell_text_.*": "Getoasteter",
  "_version_": 1578390437688770600
}
```

Here is a stripped down version of the class I'm using:

```
public class ExampleDoc {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Field("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName(value="spell_text_en-us",
      alternate={
        "spell_text_de",
        "spell_text_fr"
      }
    }
    @Field("spell_text_*")
    public String spellText;
}
```

My assumption is that I have the spellText field declared incorrectly, and that it should be declared like this:

```
@SerializedName(value="spell_text_en-us",
  alternate={
    "spell_text_de",
    "spell_text_fr"
  }
}
@Field("spell_text_*")
public Map<String, String> spellText;
```

However, if I declare the field as a Map then the Gson parser isn't able to deserialize the json into an ExampleDoc.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!
Lee

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to use the Map as listed in the question:

```
@Field("spell_text_*")
public Map<String, String> spellText;
```

I went to the SolrJ code base and looked through the unit tests to see what the code was expecting.

I then needed to change the code to read in the various spell_text fields from the JSON, and update the spellText map with the field name and value. I decided to make one document class for the Gson code to use (although I could have used JsonObject.get("spell_text_"), and another class for SolrInputDocument.